# Оптимизация подключения к БД

Tags: php, mvc, pdo

Делаю сайт на паттерне MVC. В каждой модели есть методы, получающие данные, т.е. к примеру

```
public static function checkEmailExists($email)
{
    // Соединение с БД
    $db = Db::getConnection();

    // Текст запроса к БД
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = :email';

    // Получение результатов. Используется подготовленный запрос
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();

    if ($result->fetchColumn()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Сначала в каждом из них соединялся к БД через `Db::getConnection()`. Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в этом смысл? Быть может, лучше соединиться с БД 1 раз в контроллере? Как лучше быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: а Вы уверены, что оно именно каждый раз "соединяется" с бд? покажите содержимое метода getConnection (предварительно заменив там пароли, название бд и прочее).

Comment: На мой взгляд в `getConnection` следует использовать *singleton* чтобы он возвращал уже существующее соединение в случае когда оно повторно запрошено (при отсутствии разницы в параметрах).

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, совершенно верно - подключение к БД всегда должно быть только одно, а постоянные соединения в каждой функции тупо убьют сервер.

Во-вторых, надо отдавать себе отчет, что никаким MVC здесь и не пахнет. Набор статических методов - это старое доброе процедурное программирование, вид сбоку.

Поэтому если отвечать в контексте используемого в данный момент подхода, то для разрозненных функций, разумеется, подойдет только статический же [синглтон](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#singleton). Но в этом случае непонятно, зачем ему отдельный метод для коннекта. Надо сразу запрос и выполнять.

```
public static function checkEmailExists($email)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = ?';
    return DB::run($sql, [$email])->fetchColumn();
}
```

Если же говорить про MVC, то в контроллере не должно быть никаких подключений вообще. А в *модели* не должно быть никакой статики, соединение должно передаваться в конструктор и присваиваться переменной класса. Из которой оно потом и должно использоваться во всех методах:

```
public function __construct($pdo)
{
    $this->db = $pdo;
}
public function checkEmailExists($email)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = ?';
    $result = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute([$email]);
    return $result->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: т.е. нужно, чтобы каждая каждая модель имела доступ к классу pdo? Как лучше это сделать? Экстендить в каждую модель класс pdo?

Comment: Если экстендить, то в итоге получится та же тыща коннектов. Ка сделать, показано выше - передавать в конструктор при создании объекта.

Comment: т.е. каждая модель должна инициализироваться? Получается, чтобы получить результат функции `checkEmailExists()`, нужно сначала сделать `$user = new User(); $emailexists = $User->checkEmailExists($email)`? И да, а что нужно передавать в конструктор? Т.е. `$user = new User(что сюда?)` получается, сам объект pdo нужно инициализировать в контроллере, а потом уже передавать его в модель?

Comment: По хорошему, в контроллере не должно быть никаких подключений. В лучшем случае подключение в контроллер должно передаваться как сервис. Но обычно так не делают. В Симфони в контроллер передается Доктрина, которая и работает с моделями. В Ларавелевском говнокоде модель выглядит как у тебя - статическим классом, но это фасад, который инициализирует модель внутри себя.